# Taylor limit on a number $\cos(0.1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, limits, taylor-expansion

I have $f(x)=\cos(x)$ at the point $x_0=0$.

Using the Taylor polynomial of degree 2, we approximate the number $\cos(0.1)$.

What I did is take the Taylor equation

$$cos(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)/1!+f''(a)((x-a)^2)/2!+f'''(a)((x-a)^3)/3!+...$$

After that, I put $a=0$ on this equation

$$cos(x)=f(0)+f'(0)(0-a)/1!+f''(0)((0-a)^2)/2!+f"(0)((0-a)^3)/3!+...$$

I have $\sum$ but I can't understand how to use $cos(0.1)$ where I should.

Comment: You need to compute $f(0)=\cos(0)=1$, $f'(0)=-\sin(0)=0$, $f''(0)=-\cos(0)=-1$, ... Then actually put $a=0$, instead of $x=0$ in the formula. Finally, put $x=0.1$.

Comment: yes SORRY! I FORGOT BRO

Comment: i have done this but good point you wrote it

Comment: you mean to put x=0.1 on cos(x)=f(a)+f′(a)(x−a)/1!+f′′(a)((x−a)2)/2!+f′′′(a)((x−a)3)/3!+... ?i understand good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to tidy up your expressions, because they seem to be confusing you (you keep some of the $f$s and $a$s around when they should've been gone). Here is a tidier version verson of more or less exactly what you have:

For a given infinitely differentiable function $f$, the Taylor approximation / polynomial of $f$ of degree $n$ around the point $a$ is given as
$$
f(x) \approx f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + \frac{f''(a)}{2}(x-a)^2 + \cdots + \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n
$$
You are told to use degree $2$, so we set $n = 2$ and get
$$
f(x) \approx f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + \frac{f''(a)}{2}(x-a)^2
$$
We are interested in the function $f(x) = \cos(x)$, so we insert that. Remember that $[\cos(a)]' = -\sin(a)$ and $[\cos(a)]'' = -\cos(a)$:
$$
\cos(x) \approx \cos(a) - \sin(a)(x-a) - \frac{\cos(a)}{2}(x-a)^2
$$
Note that all the $f$s are gone.

Now we insert $a = 0$ into this and get
$$
\cos(x) \approx \cos(0) - \sin(0)(x-0) - \frac{\cos(0)}{2}(x-0)^2
$$
Note that all the $a$s are gone.

At this point, we can insert the well-known values of $\cos(0)$ and $\sin(0)$, as well as simplify $x-0$ to $x$, and get our final approximation ready to go: swap out $x$ with $0.1$ on both sides and calculate.

Comment: cos(x)≈cos(0)−sin(0)(x−0)−cos(0)2(x−0)2 on this i put x=0.1? i understand 100% what you told me ,but i want to check if i understand and this too.Perfect you told me nice and i am very thankful .Good and thank you a lot

Comment: You take your expression, or mine (regardless I suggest you simplify first), and you take all the $x$s you see, and you swap them out and put $0.1$ where the $x$s were. Then you calculate.

Comment: thanks a lot :)